# How to assign the length of an array to a number type variable in Angular 11?

Tags: angular, methods, get, variable-assignment, angular11

So here is my problem, I have this going on my `app.component.ts` :

```
@Component({
selector: 'sa-app',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

numberEditing: number = 0;

 constructor(
private measureService: MeasureService,
) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
 this.editing()
}

editing() {
    this.medidorService.getEditing().subscribe(editingProcess => this.numberEditing = editingProcess.length) // if I console.log(editingProcess.length) I do get the number correctly.
    console.log(this.numberEditing) // UNDEFINED
    this.test(this.numberEditing)
  }

 test(numberEditing) {
   console.log(numberEditing) // UNDEFINED
 }
```

And whenever I console.log(editingProcess.length) I do get the number that I want to assign to

```
this.numberEditing,
```

however, if I console.log this.numberEditing, AFTER the assignment, it is always undefined.

I tried moving the `this.measureService.getEditing().subscribe(editingProcess => this.numberEditing = editingProcess.length)` to inside the constructor, the result is the same.
I tried making this.numberEditing into an array or an object and the object comes empty and the array doesn't work, I get:

```
Type 'Measure[]' is not assignable to type '[]'.
  Target allows only 0 element(s) but source may have more.
```

I want to use the value in numberEditing in a data chart, so I need to be able to save the value in the variable and use it after I get it, right in the component.ts , HTML is not going to be used.

I do understand that I am using an observable, so by the time I have the value on my editingProcess.length, everything else has already loaded.

---

> But then, how do I make the variable or the function that calls the
> variable wait for this to happen to only then - assign the value?

---

The whole service was not made by me but I can access and see it, it does return something and it does return the array that I want along with the items inside it correctly, I am 100% sure the problem is on my end.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you subscribe to an observable, that code running is **asynchronous**, meaning, it will run sometime in the future, the outer console.log runs first, because is **synchronous**.

```js
numberEditing = 0;

editing(): void {
  this.medidorService.getEditing().subscribe((v) => {
    this.numberEditing = v;
    console.log('inside subscribe: ', this.numberEditing)
  });
  console.log('outside subscribe', this.numberEditing)
}
```

The output will be:

```
 //outside subscribe 0
 //inside subscribe: 100
```

Even though the outer console log is after the subscribe, the outer console log executes first.

Whatever you need to handle after you get `getEditing()` do it inside the instance of `subscribe`, not outside.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to async.

Try to use: async/await.

In your case, I split to getData() method to get data first:

```
async getData() {
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.medidorService.getEditing().subscribe(editingProcess => this.numberEditing = editingProcess.length)
       })}
```

After that, using await to fetch data:

```
    editing() {
        this.numberEditing = await getData();
        console.log(this.numberEditing)
        this.test(this.numberEditing)
      }
```

Hope that it helps you.

Comment: This is not a problem of `async/await`. `getEditing()` returns an observable, there is no need to transform it to a promise... too complicated just for getting a response. Make use of `observables` along with `RxJs` operators

Comment: Thank your comment @Andres2142. But have you read the author's question? "_I do understand that I am using an observable, so by the time I have the value on my editingProcess.length, everything else has already loaded. But then, how do I make the variable or the function that calls the variable wait for this to happen to only then - assign the value?_"